# How to pass value From one php page to another?

Tags: php, session-cookies

Page1.php has one submit button and a variable $a=1.when i click submit button it goes to page2.php and updates the value of $a to $a=2  and instantly comes back to page1.php and print that updated value.  I tried with session data,but failed.pls help

Comment: Sessions do seem potentially appropriate. If they're not working, you'll need to provide more information and your relevant code.

Comment: Please add your attempt using sessions (feel free to edit your question).

Answer (score 0):

Here is some basic code that submits a value (from the submit button), to another page using the HTTP GET method.  The second page checks to see if a numerical string is passed and if so increases the value by one, and then uses a http redirect to instruct the client to go back to the original page.  That page checks to see if the value is passed via the URL, and if so displays it.

First page:

```
<?php
$a = isset($_GET['a']) ? $_GET['a'] : null;
if(ctype_digit($a)) {
    echo $a;
} else {
?>
    <form method=get action=page2.php>
        <input type=submit name=a value=1>
    </form>
<?php 
}
```

Second page:

```
<?php
$a = isset($_GET['a']) ? $_GET['a'] : null;
if(ctype_digit($a)) {
    $a++;
    $url = 'page1.php?a=' . urlencode($a);
    header("Location: $url");
    exit;
}
```

If I've misunderstood your question, please feel free to clarify your original question.

Comment: It's showing an error "Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '?' in C:\xampp\htdocs\1\one.php on line 3"

Comment: @JobayerRifad, I guess you are using a pre-php 7 version.  I've swapped out the null coalescing operator for the equivalent ternary.  Try that.  Mind you, line 3?